# Can I late bind to event handlers in C#?

Tags: c#, event-handling, late-binding

I'm creating objects dynamically and inserting them into an html table, the objects are either labels or linkbuttons, if they are linkbuttons i need to subscribe an eventhandler to the click event, but I'm struggling to find a way to actually add the handler. The code so far is:

```
WebControl myControl;

if _createLabel)
{
    myControl = new Label();
}
else
{
    myControl = new LinkButton();
}

myControl.ID = "someID";
myControl.GetType().InvokeMember("Text", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, myControl,  new object[] { "some text" });

if (!_createLabel)
{
    // somehow do myControl.Click += myControlHandler; here
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that will work.

[myControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.aspx).[GetType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx).[GetEvent("Click")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getevent.aspx).[AddEventHandler(myControl, myControlHandler)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.eventinfo.addeventhandler.aspx);

Answer (score 7):

The following will work:

```
LinkButton lnk = myControl as LinkButton;
if (lnk != null)
{
    lnk.Click += myControlHandler;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This shows binding an event on a control (by name) to a method on the current instance (by name):

```
Button btn = new Button();
EventInfo evt = btn.GetType().GetEvent("Click");
MethodInfo handler = GetType().GetMethod("SomeHandler",
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
evt.AddEventHandler(btn, Delegate.CreateDelegate(
        evt.EventHandlerType, this, handler));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do:

Control.Event += new EventHandlerType(this.controlClick);

Comment: I can't use:

myControl.Click += myControlHandler;

as WebControl doesn't have a click event so the code won't compile